# How to clear sync.Map

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency

option 1:

```golang
cache.Range(func(key, value interface{}) bool {
    cache.Delete(key)
    return true
})
```

option 2:

```golang
cache = sync.Map{}
```

I want to flush cache and **option 1** don't look good.

But I am not sure that **option 2** is safe when other goroutine is `Storing` or `Loading`.

Comment: If this is really is a problem, then sync.Map is not the right data structure for your task. From the docs: "The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry for a
    given key is only ever written once but read many times, as in caches that
    only grow, or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite
    entries for disjoint sets of keys. In these two cases, use of a Map may
    significantly reduce lock contention compared to a Go map paired with a
    separate Mutex or RWMutex."

Comment: @Volker  I see, thx. ps https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sync.Map`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) does not support removing all elements, your option 1 is how you can do it if necessary.

Your option 2  changes the value of the `cache` variable, so if `cache` is accessed from multiple goroutines, this operation will cause a data race unless access to the `cache` variable itself is synchronized.

If you frequently need to clear the map, then `sync.Map` may not be the best choice. Consider using a simple map with [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) then. If you do this, to clear the map you may simply create and assign a new map while holding the lock.